# Adding a custom transition causes xib to load for the wrong screen size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to add a custom transition to a UIViewController which has a xib. I have tried a few approaches but they all have the same issue, the view displays for the wrong screen size.

My current example is based on the following tutorial: [Custom UIViewController transition in iOS with Swift](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/custom-uiviewcontroller-transition-ios-swift/)

I have made no changes to the TransitionDelegate or Animators.

Here's the view in the xib and in the simulator:

[image: UIViewController Loads For Wrong Size]

The white UIView is set to centre, 80% width with a 1:1 ratio.

My UIViewController is loaded using the following:

```
let thirdViewController = ThirdViewController()
    thirdViewController.transitioningDelegate = viewTransitionDelegate
    thirdViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    navigationController?.present(thirdViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I comment out setting the delegate the view will load 100% perfectly:

[image: UIViewController Loads Correctly Without Transition Delegate]

Finally, I have another UIViewController which has no xib and the constraints are set programmatically. This view is loaded with the same transition and loads perfectly:

[image: UIViewController Loads Correctly Without XIB]

What do I need to change to get this working with XIBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent ages looking for an answer to this and then found it from [one of the related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104481/custom-viewcontroller-transition-doesnt-resize-properly?rq=1) in the sidebar.

All I needed to do was add the following to my animator:

```
toViewController.view.frame = fromViewController.view.frame
```

I hope this helps someone one day.

Comment: Amazing!!! Works fine! I tried to use every type of "layout subviews solution", but apparently when using custom transitions, a xib or storyboard file is overwritten.