# There's a way to share UI elements between two viewControllers?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, transition, viewcontroller

I need to execute a transition between two view controllers in a smooth way, like a have just one view controller and performing simple animations. For example, an element from VC1 will exit from the view and in the same time, an element from VC2 will be entering in the visible screen. Sorry, but I don't have how to show this.

Comment: Start from here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/261-how-to-make-a-uiviewcontroller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app

Comment: Thanks a lot @KeshuR. this is exactly what I want, I'm just having some trouble with layout after using the custom transition, I think it's because I loading the next ViewController from a xib file.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found a simple solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541659/adding-a-custom-transition-causes-xib-to-load-for-the-wrong-screen-size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use this library [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero). 
It perfectly provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this framework before, it's great, but I trying to not use external libraries.